# Abstract Classes in OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

I am having very strange behavior in my abstract class.

here is my code :

```
<?php

class Hello {

    public abstract function sayHello();

}

class Hey extends Hello {

public function sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}

}


$greeting = new Hey;

echo $greeting->sayHello();
```

**So, I am expecting result:** Hello

But I cant understand why I am getting following ***error*** :

> Fatal error: Class Hello contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Hello::sayHello) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/oop/abstract.php on line 7

What am I missing?

Comment: The error message says it clearly: *"... and must therefore be declared `abstract` ..."*. Read about [abstract classes and methods in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: Come on man....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missing to declare class as abstract :

```
// here, class should be declared as abstract
abstract class Hello {

    public abstract function sayHello();

}

class Hey extends Hello {

    public function sayHello(){
        return "Hello";
    }

}


$greeting = new Hey;

echo $greeting->sayHello();
```

Outputs :

```
hello
```